# write output with delimiter in python

Tags: python

I want to save my output as csv file with custom name and delimiter.
I tried this code but now works for me.

```
out = open('out.csv', 'w')
for row in l:
for column in row:
    out.write('%d;' % column)
out.write('\n')
out.close()
```

Here is my data

```
100A7E54111FB143    
100D11CF822BBBDB    
1014120EE9CCB1E0    
10276825CD5B4A26    
10364F56076B46B7    
103D1DDAD3064A66    
103F4F66EEB54308    
104310B0280E4F20    
104E80752424B1C3    
106BE9DBB186BEC5    
10756F745D8A4123    
107966C82D8BAD8
```

I want to save like this

```
input.csv
input_id data
number   107966C82D8BAD8 | 10756F745D8A4123 | 106BE9DBB186BEC5
```

The delmiter would be '|'.The data is in dtype:object

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: Replace `out.write('\n')` to `out.write(' | ')` but your end char is ` | ` so detect `end line iscoming`(`if is last element`).

Answer (score 6):

Use a writer for the CSV object instead:

```
import csv

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(out, delimiter='|')
    spamwriter.writerow(column)
```

I have omitted your for loop

Comment: Sorry, i couldnt get the indentation correctly from my mobile. Markdown issues

Comment: I am getting the following error...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: Make sure the `for` loop is within the scope of the `with` statement

Answer (score 3):

One simple way is to use print of python 3.x, If you are using python 2.x then import print from future

```
from __future__ import print_function   #Needed in python 2.x 

print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)
```

Comment: just a hint, one can use unpacking here: `print(*row, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet of code as an example. I did something similar in my program, creating a text file with a comma separator, no csv module involved. Not sure about newlines. I just used it for one line in my case...

```
        cachef_h = [a,b,c,d]
        f = open('cachef_h.txt', 'x')
           f.write(cachef_h[0])
           for column_headers in cachef_h[1:]:
           f.write(',' + column_headers)
```